# How to get live running status of an Indian train?

Tags: trains, india

Which is the best option to get live running status of an Indian train?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Answer (score 4):

Following are are 2 websites which I found very accurate and they refresh the status frequently:

1. Official PNR enquiry website:
   http://www.indianrail.gov.in/enquiry/PNR/PnrEnquiry.html?locale=en.
   After entering your PNR, you can check live running status, seating charts etc. Here PNR (short for Passenger Name Record) is kind of an itinerary id and printed on (e)ticket.
2. On Etrain.info private website where schedule, route map, and live running
   status can be checked. Example:
   https://etrain.info/in?TRAIN=14258

In addition to above there are a few IRCTC (Indian Railway Catering and Tourism Corporation) apps that can be downloaded on your smartphone to check status of train, tickets, or food menu. (Search IRCTC in the app store or google play).

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comment, NTES (National Train Enquiry System) of Indian Railways is the true source of the information. Its website is https://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes and it also has an app (Search NTES in the app store or google play).

Comment: National Train Enquiry System (NTES) is the main system. All updates are fed there and all other apps, websites source the data from there.

Comment: Thanks @RedBaron. Edited the answer to include NTES info.

Comment: Great, I found https://etrain.info/in to be more user friendly and attractive than NTES.